# Some images not being returned with wp_get_attachment_image

Tags: wp-query, attachments, images

For some reason this code works on my local copy of a wordpress site but the live site is not working.

```
// WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'post_type'               => 'post',
        'pagination'             => false,
        'posts_per_page'     => '99',
        'category_name' => 'wedding'
    );

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();

            $thumb_ID = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
            $blogimages = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'blogimages', true ); 
            if ( $images = get_children(array(
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                    'exclude' => [
                        $thumb_ID,
                        isset( $blogimages[0]['blog-image-inside'] ) ? $blogimages[0]['blog-image-inside'] : 0,
                        isset( $blogimages[0]['blog-image-front'] ) ? $blogimages[0]['blog-image-front'] : 0,
                        isset( $blogimages[0]['blog-image-main'] ) ? $blogimages[0]['blog-image-main'] : 0
                    ],
                ))) : 
                foreach( $images as $image ) : 
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID).'" rel="nivo" data-lightbox-gallery="wedding">';
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, array(360,999));
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                endforeach;
    else: // No images
        //This post has no attached images
    endif;
        }
    }
    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

I have one post under the wedding category, with 5 images attached and none of the images are being displayed, is there any reason why that code may not be working? Yet it works perfectly on my local version?

In checking my php versions my remote server is running 5.4.26 and my local was on 5.5.10, when I changed local to the same as the remote version it stops working, so it seems to be something with that code on 5.4.26?

After messing with the code again I have come up with this bit of code here...

```
 $args = array(
        'category_name' => 'wedding',
        'pagination' => false,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
     );
     $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $blogimages = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'blogimages', true ); 
            $attachments = get_posts(array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                'exclude' => [
                    get_post_thumbnail_id(),
                    isset( $blogimages[0]['blog-image-inside'] ) ? $blogimages[0]['blog-image-inside'] : 0,
                    isset( $blogimages[0]['blog-image-front'] ) ? $blogimages[0]['blog-image-front'] : 0,
                    isset( $blogimages[0]['blog-image-main'] ) ? $blogimages[0]['blog-image-main'] : 0
                ]
            ));

            if($attachments){
                foreach($attachments as $attachment){
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID).'" rel="nivo" data-lightbox-gallery="wedding">';
                    echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, array(360,999),true);
                    echo '</a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No images found for this category';
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

But I am now noticing that if I remove or add images to posts they are not being reflected, but if I delete the post entirely, even after I've already removed images from it, they finally get removed from the gallery page. Also if I add a new post with images under the specified category, the images are not being added to the gallery. Why is this happening, is there some sort of caching thing going on?

Comment: Are you sure that remote PHP version is 5.4+?

Comment: What is resulting output in page source on live site? Do you get any errors with `WP_DEBUG` enabled?

Comment: I set godaddy to run 5.5 and still no luck, Also with `WP_DEBUG` on there are not errors being displayed.

Comment: Also when I set it back to the 'suggested' version which didn't tell me what version it was, I made a phpinfo() page and it says I have 5.4.26, I checked my local version and I was running 5.5.10, so I switched it to the same version and lo and behold, it stops working locally as well. Now we are getting some where hopefully. So the question still remains why is that code not working on 5.4.26?

Comment: I'm now noticing some caching it seems, please see my updated code above